# Data from Timestamp

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I try to show the right day to some specific timestamps but I get for different days every time to 31st day and for the last 3 timestamps 30th day.

```
$old_date = date("Y-m-t", $timestamp);
```

Left you can see the output and right the timestamp:

> 2017-10-31 - 1507326468,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507409268,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507492068,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507574869,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507657669,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507740469,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507823270,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507906070,
>   2017-10-31 - 1507988870,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508071671,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508154471,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508237271,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508320072,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508402872,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508485672,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508568472,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508651273,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508734073,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508816873,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508899674,
>   2017-10-31 - 1508982474,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509065274,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509148075,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509230875,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509313675,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509396476,
>   2017-10-31 - 1509479276,
>   2017-11-30 - 1509562076,
>   2017-11-30 - 1509644876,
>   2017-11-30 - 1509727676

---

Edit: 
I have to write:

```
$old_date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Stupid mistake.

Comment: `strtotime('-30 days');` but it's better to use DateTime class

Comment: Thank you :) You answere fast :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` you use in the `date("Y-m-t", $timestamp);` stands for 'Number of days in the given month'. [See the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) You probably want to use `j`, which stands for 'Day of the month without leading zeros'.

Comment: Oh I missed it. I want to use `d`